# Android Touch Events Pointer Down

Tags: android, touch

Hi I am trying to detect when 2 fingers are touching the screen:

```
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN: {

    twoFing=true;
    return true;
}
```

the problem is that:

```
public static final int ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN
```

is depreceted, the doc says:

*Constant for getActionMasked(): A non-primary pointer has gone down.
Use getActionIndex() to retrieve the index of the pointer that changed.
The index is encoded in the ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK bits of the unmasked action returned by getAction().*

but I don't understand how to use it... How could I detect that there are 2 pointers? ActionUP and DOwn always say there is only one pointer if I try getPointerIndex()

thanks a lot

EDIT: I post here the full code to be more clear about the problem. My code is working BUT as the ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN is a deprecated value I want to replace it by something else but I don't know how.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

switch(event.getAction()){

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : {
     Log.i(TAG, "Action Down");
    downX = event.getX(0);
    downY = event.getY(0);
    return true;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {


    upX = event.getX(0);
    upY = event.getY(0);

    float deltaX = downX - upX;
    float deltaY = downY - upY;
    Log.i(TAG, "Action UP deltaX="+deltaX+", deltaY="+deltaY);



    // swipe vertical?
    if(Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE && twoFing){
        twoFing=false;

        // top or down
        if(deltaY < 0 ) 
        { 
            if(slide.zoom==1) 
            slide.zoom=0; 
        Log.i(TAG, "Going Down zooming in");
            //return true; 
        }
        if((deltaY > 0) )
        { 

            if(slide.zoom==0) 
                slide.zoom=1;  
            Log.i(TAG, "Going up zoomig out");
            //return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
    // swipe horizontal?
  if(Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE && !twoFing){

        // left or right
        if(deltaX < 0) { this.slideToTheLeft(); return true; }
        if(deltaX > 0) { this.slideToTheRight(); return true; }
        return true;
    }

  return false;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN: {

    twoFing=true; //inform that the touch was made with 2 fingers
    Log.i(TAG, "Action Second pointer down");

    return true;
}
}
return false;
```

}

Answer (score 8):

I'm working on pointer stuff myself right now. You want to switch as follows

```
 switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK);
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
```

ACTION_DOWN is about the first finger down.
ACTION_POINTER_DOWN is about the second finger.

See http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTouch/article.html for a fairly clear description.

Comment: This works for me. I am using Kotlin, so I just had to change `switch` statement to `when (event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) `

Answer (score 2):

*MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN* is only for the first pointer.  GetActionMasked() will return *MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN* for subsequent pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `getPointerId(index)` with different values for `index` ?

See the difference between Id and Index:

> **Index vs. ID**
>
> At a higher level, touchscreen data from a snapshot in time may not be
> immediately useful since touch gestures involve motion over time
> spanning many motion events. A pointer index does not necessarily
> match up across complex events, it only indicates the data’s position
> within the MotionEvent. However this is not work that your app has to
> do itself. Each pointer also has an ID mapping that stays persistent
> across touch events. You can retrieve this ID for each pointer using
> MotionEvent.getPointerId(index) and find an index for a pointer ID
> using MotionEvent.findPointerIndex(id).

The best solution should be to save the state of all the pointers and update/compare them you receive a new TouchEvent.

Check this [example](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html).

Comment: I am only getting data from the first pointer (0) as I don't need precise data. I only need to detect that the second finger was also pressed (case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN:) so then I set a variable and then on action up my logic detects if there was a 2 finger or 1 but I need to replace the ACTION_POINTER_2 by something else.....

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to trigger `case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, then check retrieve PointerId.

Does your device really support multitouch ?